# Node + Express Router - returning images

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building an imgur mirror - i.e. if somebody wants to view imgur.com/asdf.jpg on my domain, they just go to mydomain.com/asdf.jpg and it opens the image. Here's a code snippet I've some up with so far; however, it's asking me to download the file and isn't outputting it as an image in the browser. Looking for help with this issue. Thanks.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router = express();

  router.get('/*', function(req, res) {

      var image = "http://i.imgur.com/"+req.params[0];
      console.log(image); // captures correctly the image name
      request
      .get(image)
      .on('response', function(response) {
        res.writeHead(response.statusCode, "{\'Content-Type: \'"+response.headers['content-type']+"\'}");
      })
      .pipe(res);
  });

... some server stuff
```

Comment: and, what does `response.headers['content-type']` contain?

Comment: text/html; charset=utf-8 ... probably the problem ... should I be somehow capturing the extension of req.params[0] and injecting that into the content-type line?

Comment: probably, i'm not sure what content type you'll need for each extension though. I'm sure there's a list somewhere

Comment: You're probably missing some additional information required by imgur, such as headers typically sent by a browser (e.g. maybe it's expecting a `User-Agent` header). Or perhaps the URL you're using isn't actually the direct link to the image.

Comment: @glog You can use [res.type()](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.type) method to set the correct mime type to your header. All you need is calling it like this: `res.type(req.params[0].split('.').pop())`

But it's hard to say because http://i.imgur.com/ is blocked in Turkey, so I can't test.

Comment: Are you rendering the image somewhere? or are you just sending it back to the client? I think thats why its asking you to download the file. You're sending the image back to the client instead of rendering it.

Comment: I've tested your code, it's Ok, you should check your browser instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is with setting the content type you could set the content type using the following code:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
```

Or you can use:

```
res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(err.status).end();
    }
    else {
       console.log('Sent:', fileName);
   }
});
```

Which sets the content type based on the file extension as the [docs suggest](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile).